# double espresso test with gradle - empty test suite

Tags: testing, gradle, android-studio, android-espresso

I'm trying to use espresso to test my aplication. As I found in other postes I shall use double espresso insted of pure espresso with gradle. Doulbe espresso can be found here: https://github.com/JakeWharton/double-espresso.

I configured a run configuration like this: http://wiki.android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git/android-studio-new-run-configuration.png. When I execute it, after a while it says Empty Test Suite

I created the following test class in androidTest/java directory: 
package com.myapp.mobileapp.test.ui;

```
@LargeTest
public class LoginTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<LoginActivity> {

    public LoginTest(Class<LoginActivity> activityClass) {
        super(activityClass);
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
        getActivity();
    }

    @SmallTest
    public void testLogin() {
        onView(withId(R.id.buttonLogin))
                .perform(click());
        assertTrue(true);
    }
}
```

My project has a top project that has the apk project and the facebook library project.

The build file for the top project is the following:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all     sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.11.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

the build file for the apk project is the following:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 18
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    // https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=71147
    useOldManifestMerger true

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.mobileapp"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 18

        testApplicationId "com.myapp.mobileapp.test"   
        testInstrumentationRunner "com.google.android.apps.common.testing.testrunner.GoogleInstrumentationTestRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.txt'
        }
        debug {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-    rules.pro'
        }
    }

    packagingOptions {
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/license.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
        exclude 'LICENSE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/notice.txt'
        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
        exclude 'META-INF/ASL2.0'
    }
}

dependencies {

// OTHERS
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:18.0.0'
    compile('com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4')

    // GOOGLE PLAY SERVICES
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:3.2.65'

    // FACEBOOK
    compile project(':facebookSDK')

    // CHAT LIBRARY
    compile files('libs/asmack-android-18-0.8.10.jar')

    // GOOGLE ANALITICS
    compile files('libs/libGoogleAnalyticsServices.jar')

    // ORMLITE
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-core:4.41'
    compile 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.41'

    // ROBOSPICE
    compile('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice:1.4.6') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('com.octo.android.robospice:robospice-spring-android:1.4.6') {
        exclude module: 'support-v4'
    }
    compile('org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.9.11')

    // LOGGING
    compile files('libs/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar')
    compile files('libs/logback-android-1.0.10-2.jar')

    // VOLLEY
    compile files('libs/volley.jar')

        // TESTING TOOLS    
        androidTestCompile('com.jakewharton.espresso:espresso:1.1-r3')
    }
```

---

I´m using the following tools:

Android Studio 0.6.1

### (built in gradle in android studio) gradlew --version

### Gradle 1.10

Build time:2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC
Build number:none
Revision:36ced393628875ff15575fa03d16c1349ffe8bb6

Groovy:1.8.6

Ant:Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2

Ivy:2.2.0

JVM:1.8.0_05 (Oracle Corporation 25.5-b02)

OS:Windows 8.1 6.3 amd64

Comment: Did this answer resolve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably getting an exception, so check the logs.

The constructor needs to be like this:

```
public LoginTest() {
    super(LoginActivity.class);
}
```

Similar question and answer:
[Espresso testing android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24265264/espresso-testing-android)